# How can I turn off speaking of incoming caller?

Tags: chrome-for-android, android-versions, samsung-galaxy-s-duos-2

I can't figure out how to change the settings on my Samsung Galaxy S phone to actually have a ringtone when receiving a call.

When receiving a call a voice says "call from 123-456-7890" or "call from Fred". I know how to set the ringtone which has been set but I don't know how to take the voice off.

I tried *accessibility* and *talk back*, there are no option for driving mode but it is still speaking caller name.

What to do??

Comment: Please add a screen shot of your driving mode options and check whether Talk back is enabled in your driving mode.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you can do us head over to the Settings>Accessibility>Vision>Tap over Talkback>Tap on Settings over the Talkback window>Uncheck speak caller ID, that should fix your problem out.